# Yii Ajax Validation in widget not working

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm using Ajax validation in my widget. here is the code.

Widget function

```
public function run(){

if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
    $this->controller->redirect('/');
}

$model= new LoginForm;

// if it is ajax validation request
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
{
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        // blah blah.......
```

Widget View:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=> true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('placeholder'=>'email','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('placeholder'=>'password','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block')); ?>
    </div>
    ...
```

- Right now the form is not submitting. After I click login nothing happens.
- If I make enableAjaxValidation fale, form works but not AJAX.
- If I make enableClientValidation false, form works **but still no AJAX.**

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you are using a single submit button, instead of an ajax submit button.

For this, you may use, for example, an ajaxSubmitButton widget from Yii Bootstrap (or Yii booster).

So, in the SiteController :

```
...
$model= new LoginForm;

if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
{
  echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
  Yii::app()->end();
}
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
{
  $model->unsetAttributes();
  $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];

  if($model->validate() && $model->login())
  {
    $array = array('login' => 'success');
    $json = json_encode($array);
    echo $json;

    Yii::app()->end();
  }
  else{ //This is the important point
    if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest()) 
    {
      $array=$model->getErrors();
      $json = json_encode($array);
      echo $json; //JSON containing the errors set in /models/LoginForm.php
      Yii::app()->end(); 
    }
  }
}
...
```

In your view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'login-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=> true,
  'enableClientValidation'=>true,
  'clientOptions'=>array(
     'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
   ),
  )); 
?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('placeholder'=>'email','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('placeholder'=>'password','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row" >
    <?php 
      /** THIS IS THE AJAX SUBMIT BUTTON **/
     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                        'buttonType' => 'ajaxSubmit', 
                        'label' => 'Login', 
                        'ajaxOptions' => array(
                               'success' => 
                                   'function(data){
                                       var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                                       if(obj.login=="success"){
                                          //...
                                          // $(location).attr("href","BASEURL/someController/someAction")
                                       }
                                       else{
                                           if("username" in obj){
                                               $("#LoginForm_username_em_").text(obj.username[0]);
                                               $("#LoginForm_username_em_").show();
                                               $("#LoginForm_username").css({"background":"#FEE","border-color":"#C00"});
                                           }

                                           if("password" in obj){
                                               $("#LoginForm_password_em_").text(obj.password[0]);
                                               $("#LoginForm_password").css({"display":"block"});
                                               $("#LoginForm_password").css({"background":"#FEE","border-color":"#C00"});
                                           }
                                          $("#LoginForm_password_em_").show();
                                       }
                          }'),
                    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

In order to use the ajaxSubmitButton widget of Yii Bootstrap (or Yii Booster), you have to download it from http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/, extract it in your /protected/extensions folder and include it in /protected/config/main.php :

```
...
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap',dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap'); //booster insead of bootstrap if you download the Yii Booster.

return array(
  ...
  'components'=>array(
    ...
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap', // assuming you extracted bootstrap under extensions
    ),
  )
)
```

Yii Booster has many other widgets, for this reason I use it. If you don't want to use Yii booster for the ajax submit button, just use the CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton

Comment: thanks for the help. But I don't think the code above works. I tried var obj = $.parseJSON(data); but it always returns invalid token in the console.

Comment: Try this: In login.php, in 'ajaxOptions':
 ..
   'ajaxOptions' => array(
                                     'success' => 
                                         'function(data){
                                              var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                                              alert(data);
                                                            if(obj.login=="success"){
                                                               ...
                                                            }
                                                            else{ ..}

Comment: With that alert, you may see what the JSON is returning. 
Nevertheless, I think you missed something in the model of LoginForm.php. 
In it, you have to set the exceptions rules for the errores:
   ...
    public function rules()
 {
  return array(
                        array('username', 'required', 'message'=>'Username required.'),
                        array('password', 'required', 'message'=>'Password required.'),
  );
 }

Comment: Also, in LoginForm.php:

    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
 {
  if(!$this->hasErrors())
  {
   $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
   if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
    $this->addError('password','Incorrect password.');
  }
 }

This way, you JSON will return whatever it need to return depending on the case

Comment: I forgot to mention that in SiteController.php, in function actionLogin(),  add the following code when login succeeds:

    if($model->validate() && $model->login())
                    {
                        $array = array('login' => 'success');
                        $json = json_encode($array);
                        echo $json;

                       Yii::app()->end();
                    }

 (I edited it in the code above).

Answer (score 0):

Ajax validation needs a bit of care.
Please check response at console for ajax call. In ajax validation the output of ajax call should be pure json. In case of ajax validation from widget may include some html with response of ajax call.

have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12222-ajax-validation-in-widget-does-not-work/ hope it may help you.